# Docker image running incorrect command

Tags: docker

What would cause a Docker image to not run the command specified in its docker-compose.yaml file?

I have a Dockerfile like:

```
FROM python:2.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN mkdir -p /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./pip-requirements.txt pip-requirements.txt
COPY ./code /code/

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r pip-requirements.txt
```

And a docker-compose.yaml file like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  worker:
    container_name: myworker
    image: registry.gitlab.com/mygitlabuser/mygitlabproject:latest
    network_mode: host
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ./myscript.py --no-wait --traceback
```

If I build and run this locally with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up
```

The script runs for a few minutes and I get the expected output. Running `docker ps -a` shows a container called "myworker" was created, as expected.

I now want to upload this image to a repo and deploy it to a production environment by downloading and running it on a remote server.

I re-build the image with:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml build
```

and then upload it with:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com
docker push registry.gitlab.com/myuser/myproject:latest
```

This succeeds and I confirm the new image exists in my gitlab image repository.

I then login to the production server and download the image with:

```
docker login registry.gitlab.com
docker pull registry.gitlab.com/myuser/myproject:latest
```

Again, this succeeds with docker reporting:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.gitlab.com/myuser/myproject:latest
```

Running `docker images` and `docker ps -a` shows no existing images or containers.

However, this is where it gets weird. If I then try to run this image with:

```
docker run registry.gitlab.com/myuser/myproject:latest
```

nothing seems to happen. Running `docker ps -a` shows a single container with the command "python2" and the name "gracious_snyder" was created, which don't match my image. It also says the container exited immediately after launch. Running `docker logs gracious_snyder` shows nothing.

What's going on here? Why isn't my image running the correct command? It's almost like it's ignoring all the parameters in my docker-compose.yaml file and is reverting to defaults in the base python2.7 image, but I don't know why this would be because I built the image using docker-compose and it ran fine locally.

I'm running Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77 on both local and remote hosts and docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4 on my localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a command (CMD) defined in your Dockerfile, you get the upstream value from the FROM image. The compose file has some settings to build the image, but most of the values are defining how to run the image. When you run the image directly, without the compose file (docker vs docker-compose), you do not get the runtime settings defined in the compose file, only the Dockerfile settings baked into the image.

The fix is to either use your compose file, or define the CMD inside the Dockerfile like:

```
CMD ./myscript.py --no-wait --traceback
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Thanks. I didn't realize that everything in docker-compose gets lost by the image build.

Comment: @Cerin not really lost, it's just not applied yet. There's a difference between build time settings for the image and run time settings for the container.